# Android buttons equal width

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to have 2 buttons which wrap content but always stay same equal in width.

[image]

I want BUTTON 1 stretch to the width of BUTTON 2. Or if BUTTON 1 Would be wider I would need BUTTON 2 to stretch to the width of BUTTON 1

[image]

How can I achieve this? I tried using LinearLayout with weights, but it only works if linear layout width matched parent, which makes buttons unnecessary wide.

Comment: did you want in in horizontal direction or vertical direction???

Comment: Did you try to get button 2 width programming and set button 1 width ?

Comment: I want them in horizontal, and I was hoping to do this with xml only if possible.

Comment: What should happen if there's not enough space for two equal width buttons? Should `Button 1` gets smaller to accomodate for long text in `Button 2`, or should `Button 2` text get ellipsized to maintain 1:1 ratio in terms of buttons width?

Comment: Either option would be fine as long as they would stay same width when there is enough space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make both the button identical you have to calculate width of both the button like this

```
ViewTreeObserver vto1 = button1.getViewTreeObserver();
vto1.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        width = button1.getWidth();
        height = button1.getHeight();
    }
});

ViewTreeObserver vto2 = button2.getViewTreeObserver();
vto2 .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        width = button2.getWidth();
        height = button2.getHeight();
    }
});
```

then compare both the button height and set the larger one to both the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Try this!!! This may help...

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 1"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This will give the output as,

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo.
You don't need weightSum in the parent LinearLayout btw

Answer (score 3):

Use Linear Layout Weight Attribute
First Enclose Both Buttons In Linear Layout And give them horizontal orientation.
Then Give Them Equal Weights

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Try This Result

Answer (score 2):

While Ajay's answer is right, but it requires you to remove the listener once you are done with it.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto2 = button2.getViewTreeObserver();
vto2 .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        width = button2.getWidth();
        height = button2.getHeight();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            myView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
        else {
            myView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are using a **Dialog** you can use `dialog.setOnShowListener` and inside of it get/set the size of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering an old question, but there exist a one line solution.

Add `android:layout_width="0dip"` to both (i.e. all) buttons definitions in .xml file.

Another (alternative) solution is to add `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to both (all) buttons definitions.